# Filter linq/entity query results by related data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I'm using MVC5 EF6 and Identity 2.1.

I have two classes:

```
    public class Incident 
        {
           public int IncidentId {get; set;}
           ...//Title, Description, etc
           public virtual ICollection<FollowedIncident> FollowedIncidents { get; set; }
           public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        }

        public class FollowedIncident
        {
           public int FollowedIncidentId { get; set; }
           public string UserId { get; set; }
           public int IncidentId { get; set; }

           public virtual Incident Incident { get; set; }
           public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        }
```

So, the users will have the ability to follow an incident. (For starters, I'm not entirely sure if I need the ICollection and public virtual relationship references, but added them just in case for the time being.)

I'm trying to create the query that will show users the results of their followed incidents. In my controller, my query starts like this (I'm using Troy Goode's paging package... i.e. listUnpaged):

```
IQueryable<Incident> listUnpaged = db.Incidents.OrderByDescending(d => d.IncidentDate);
```

Then I want to filter by followed incidents. So, I want to show incidents where userId (parameter I pass to it) is equal to UserId in FollowedIncident. I've tried like this (error about conversion to bool from IEnumerable):

```
listUnpaged = listUnpaged.Where(s => s.FollowedIncidents.Where(t => t.UserId == userId));
```

And this (no error, but doesn't filter at all):

```
listUnpaged = listUnpaged.Where(s => s.FollowedIncidents.All(t => t.UserId == userId));
```

To me, it seems it should be as simple as this:

```
listUnpaged = listUnpaged.Where(s => s.FollowedIncidents.UserId == userId));
```

But, the linq extensions don't seem to like related data child properties? (I apologize for my programming terminology as I haven't quite pieced together all the names for everything yet.)

Anyone know how to accomplish this? It seems I may not even be thinking about it correct? (...since in the past, I've always used related data to supplement or add properties to a result. This will be the first time I want to narrow results by related data.)

Thank you.

Comment: What you are missing is `Any` (instead of `All` or `Where`):`listUnpaged = listUnpaged.Where(s => s.FollowedIncidents.Any(t => t.UserId == userId));`

Comment: @Hopeless That worked!! Thanks! I had read about the differences between `Any` and `All` and came to the conclusion, there wasn't any difference, but maybe that was more from a performance related stance? I'll keep reading. Anyway, this is why I don't gamble (with actual money)... live and learn. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you're going about getting the Incidents the wrong way.. since Incident is a navigation property of FollowedIncident you should just use

```
IQueryable<Incident> listUnpaged = db.FollowedIncidents
                                     .Where(a => a.UserId == userid)
                                     .Select(a => a.Incident)
                                     .OrderByDescending(d => d.IncidentDate);
```

Another option is to use `Any()`

```
IQueryable<Incident> listUnpaged = db.Incidents
                                 .Where(a => a.FollowedIncidents.Any(b => b.UserId == userid)
                                 .OrderByDescending(d => d.IncidentDate);
```

which would be like saying

```
Select * 
From Incidents
Where Id IN (Select IncidentId
             From FollowedIncident 
             Where UserId = @UserId)
```

Comment: `FollowedIncidents` is a navigation property of ***collection***, how could you say it works fine with this `s.FollowedIncidents.UserId`?

Comment: i was going to use Any() but for some reason it didn't look right.. I guess it's the same thing

Comment: It requires more understanding about the OP's model such as why `Incident` has related `FollowedIncidents` and in fact in this case he wants `Incidents` not `FollowedIncidents`... Using `Any` was also my guess.

Comment: it's too close to time to go home for me to check and see what the generated queries look like but seems like `.Where(a => a.UserId == userid)` would create a where = clause and `Any(a => a.UserId == userid)` would create an IN or sub join or something..  I'll add it and they can decide :)

Comment: @JamieD77 Thanks for the reply and answer, I thought about going at it from this direction (your second edit, first example), but everything is based around the Incident. So, later in the query, I'm filtering for `IsBanned` and `IsDeleted`, etc. which belong to the Incident class. Looks like Any is going to do the trick.  Thanks!

Comment: It also seems that `s.FollowedIncidents.UserId` would work if I present the related data as not an ICollection (i.e. `public virtual FollowedIncident FollowedIncidents {get; set;}`)? But, then I have a 'public bool IsFollowedIncident' I'm using somewhere else that blows up...and coincidentally uses the `Any` method...

Comment: @SumNone In the first example, you are also getting a List of Incidents because of the `.Select(a => a.Incident)` part, you're just getting the Incidents that are associated with the FollowedIncidents that you filtered.  Both queries should get you the exact same result set.